# How to fetch all the compute metrics in one REST API call?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I need to fetch all the compute metrics (CPUUtilization, MemoryUtilization, ....) in one rest api call. Currently, in documentation we can fetch only one metric related values at a time. Is there a way to achieve this?

Note: I need data for the last 10 minutes timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Each SummarizeMetricsData API call can only get data about one metric. You would need to make multiple calls to get data about all the different metrics associated with an instance.

Comment: Currently, there are 8 compute metrics, 4 boot volume metrics, (n*4) block volume metrics and (m * 6) vnic metrics.

n = Attached number of block volumes

m = Attached number of vnic's

There are a total of (8+4+n*4+m*6) metrics. It will take lot of time to call one by one. So, thought of any API to provide all the requested metrics in one go. It will be useful, if they provide.

Comment: I will pass that feedback to the service team owner, thanks